# Filter duplicates in file by using columns as parameters (grep linux)

Tags: linux, grep, ack

I am looking for the pattern `#type` in a set of files. As output I should return the lines containing that pattern. The lines are organized as columns with tab separator:

```
<subject1> <#type> <object1>
<subject2> <#type> <object1>
<subject3> <#type> <object2>
<subject4> <#type> <object2>
<subject5> <#type> <object3>
```

For this purpose I am using the command [ack-grep](http://beyondgrep.com/):

```
$ack-grep "#type"
```

I can also use **sed** as:

`sed -n -e "/#type/p;q" *.nt`

the problem is that the duplicates that I should avoid are the `objects`. As output I should be having:

```
 <subject1> <#type> <object1>
 <subject3> <#type> <object2>
 <subject5> <#type> <object3>
```

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you simply use good old grep? It should be basically:

```
grep '#type' *.nt
```

To avoid duplicates in the *objectN* part you can use uniq with the `--skip-fields` option:

```
grep '#type' *.nt | sort -k3,3 | uniq --skip-fields 2
```

However, the output needs to get sorted before using `uniq`.

Comment: I can use it @hek2mgl but the problem is with the duplicates. I can save the output  in a text file by using grep. Then write a code in c++ to remove the duplicates but they'll laugh at me lol it's not a very good idea to do it

Comment: Oh, wait I missed the part of your question where you want to replace duplicates. Let me add that

Comment: really interesting thank you @hek2mgl. If it was a google interview it would have really gone bad lololol. I was thinking of writing a C++ code lololo